# How can I access this field on json?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json

I've converted a XML into a JSON:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

This is the result:

```
"author": {
      "name": "Hey Guappo",
      "yt:userId": "asfajgf346346fghsdgsWfiqcfr1pfQ"
    }
```

and I'd like to access to the `yt:userId`.

I can't do this in .NET:

```
dynamic objectParsed = JObject.Parse(json);
var userID= (string)objectParsed.entry.author.yt:userId;
```

because of `:`. So how can I manage Namespace in JSON? I have:

```
var yt = XNamespace.Get("http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007");
```

but I don't know how to apply it...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(json);
string userId = json["author"]["yt:userId"].ToString();
```

Comment: There is no way with dynamic version?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't use the dynamic keyword myself. You could try the same code, but using dynamic instead of JObject, it's possible it would work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This WILL work with the dynamic just fine.  You don't have to use a JObject.  In addition, I've highlighted the fact that you can use . notation UP TO your "yt:userId", at which point you need to index by string value.

```
dynamic objectParsed = JObject.Parse(json);
string userId = json.author["yt:userId"].ToString();
```

There is really no reason to NOT use a JObject, as Tobberoth pointed out, but there is also no technical restriction on using a dynamic if you prefer.

As a side note, avoid using an explicit cast to string with (string).  Always use ToString().